# Mac Terminal Error about $TF_PYTHONIOENCODING;?

Tags: python, node.js, macos, terminal

When I am opening a new terminal in every new window it will spit out an error message like this:
[Error message when opening a new terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00Zol.png)

```
Fatal Python error: init_stdio_encoding: failed to get the Python codec name of the stdio encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
LookupError: unknown encoding: $TF_PYTHONIOENCODING;

Current thread 0x000000010e1e3dc0 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Also this has interfered with other global node modules working correctly e.g.

```
aws ecr get-login-password xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx.....
```

Returns an an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 27, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 23, in main
    return awscli.clidriver.main()
  File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 59, in main
    rc = driver.main()
  File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 196, in main
    parsed_args, remaining = parser.parse_known_args(args)
  File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/argparser.py", line 100, in parse_known_args
    setattr(parsed, arg, value.decode(terminal_encoding))
LookupError: unknown encoding: $TF_PYTHONIOENCODING;
```

It seems there is something wrong with $TF_PYTHONIOENCODING; but no idea what it is - I have tried googling and doesn't show any relevant searches

Comment: I don't think `$TF_PYTHONIOENCODING` is the thing that's wrong, I think it's the *value* that's been incorrectly assigned to something else (probably `PYTHONIOENCODING`). Check your various shell initialization files for these strings, and see what's happening. It sounds like a broken installation of [this program](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck/blob/c196e2901c449d96bf5116e6988610c38ca8b725/thefuck/shells/bash.py).

Comment: Hey thanks, yes I think you are right - where else should I look I tried looking at all the .zshrc and bash_profile files.. I cannot find these dam values omg I am going crazy.. Would this break modules installed by pip as well e.g. aws-cli?

Comment: Fixed it thankis a lot